# Is there any equivalent in spring like buildup in unity

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

"BuildUp" means not to create an object, but inject dependencies to an existing object according to annotations such as "Required". Expecting it will find proper beans for those dependencies automatically.